# Postgres Out of Memory

Tags: postgresql

I am setting up a new install of postgres 10.4 and during load testing I keep receiving an out of memory error.

**Configuration**:

```
 $ cat /etc/security/limits.conf
 postgres   hard    memlock 508559360
 postgres   soft    memlock 508559360


$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
vm.nr_hugepages = 248320
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 118
vm.overcommit_memory=2
vm.swappiness=1
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
kernel.sem = 250 32000 32 128
```

**System Specs**:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "core id" | wc -l
32
```

Each CPU is an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v4 @ 2.10GHz. 16 physical cores, 32 logical as shown above.

```
$ free -m
free -m
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         510969       498048      2434      3098    10485        8343
Swap:        1071         1071        0
```

**Note**: we have the memlock set at approximately 485 GB dedicated directly to postgres which shows in the high "used" column.

```
$ df -h /dev/shm
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           250G   64K  250G   1% /dev/shm

$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       523232496 kB
MemFree:         1216648 kB
MemAvailable:    8348808 kB
Buffers:           65220 kB
Cached:         10211780 kB
SwapCached:         7620 kB
Active:          5556092 kB
Inactive:        5432428 kB
Active(anon):    2208064 kB
Inactive(anon):  1593084 kB
Active(file):    3348028 kB
Inactive(file):  3839344 kB
Unevictable:       24128 kB
Mlocked:           24128 kB
SwapTotal:       1097724 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                52 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        728044 kB
Mapped:            62904 kB
Shmem:           3085592 kB
Slab:            1454276 kB
SReclaimable:    1345008 kB
SUnreclaim:       109268 kB
KernelStack:       11984 kB
PageTables:        22856 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    15770860 kB
Committed_AS:    7920136 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     71680 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:   248320
HugePages_Free:    245883
HugePages_Rsvd:     1800
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      329600 kB
DirectMap2M:    534444032 kB
```

**Postgres Info**:

```
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 10.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

max_connections=600   
shared_buffers= '8192 MB'
work_mem = '20 MB'
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
max_parallel_workers = 8
wal_buffers = 16MB
max_wal_size = 20GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = '364 GB'
default_statistics_target = 1000
log_timezone = 'US/Eastern'
track_activities = on
track_counts = on
track_io_timing = on
stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'US/Eastern'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
transform_null_equals = on
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
track_activity_query_size = 16384
track_functions = all
track_io_timing = true
pg_stat_statements.track = all
session_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'
auto_explain.log_min_duration = '3s'
auto_explain.log_nested_statements='on'
auto_explain.log_analyze=true
```

**Note**: I've started w/ work memory set as high as 250 MB and have slowly brought it down to 20 MB and still receive the errors. I've also verified that connections don't go higher than 120 connections. We use PGBouncer in front of the instance in session mode.

**The errors are too large for stack overflow but here they are linked**:

https://codepad.co/snippet/derPU4E8

The standout errors are:

```
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,28197,mydb,ERROR:  could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1552129380" to 192088 bytes: No space left on device
```

I don't understand what device its talking about. I don't have any that appear to be even close to OOM let alone the tiny 192088 bytes its talking about.

```
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,19708,mydb,ERROR:  out of memory
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,19708,mydb,DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 7232.


2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,16688,,LOG:  could not fork worker process: Cannot allocate memory
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,4555,,ERROR:  out of memory
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,4555,,DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 78336.
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,4552,,LOG:  could not open directory "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/share/timezone": Cannot allocate memory
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,19935,mydb,ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/auto_explain.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/auto_explain.so: failed to map segment from shared object


2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,28193,mydb,ERROR:  out of memory
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,28193,mydb,DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 8192.
2018-06-18 15:02:22 EDT,26927,mydb,ERROR:  could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1101931262" to 192088 bytes: No space left on device
```

**Question**: How do I debug this issue and more importantly how can I resolve it?

Comment: What does `df -h /dev/shm` report? Are you sure the huge `memlock` doesn't cause starvation of shared memory?

Comment: @DanielVérité I updated my question to include the requested information. I am unsure about the answer to the memlock question. I am open to removing it though and retesting. Will update the question once I do that sometime tomorrow. I do know that it seems that /dev/shm never seems to get more than a few MB full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed Laurenz advice and no longer run OOM.

`vm.overcommit_ratio = 100`.

Additionally, I removed the memlock and huge pages definition in sysctl/limits.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your queries are so complicated that they need to consume a large amount of temporary tablespace.

Comment: You should set `vm.overcommit_ratio = 100`, otherwise the OOM killer will get you as soon as you use half your RAM.

Comment: I will add the overcommit_ratio. @andymagoon I don't know how to check specifically. I did try creating a temp tablespace in a large filesystem (250 gigs) and that didn't seem to help any.

Comment: By setting `vm.overcommit_ratio` to 100 I've eliminated the OOM errors. I will be continuing to increase load to see if there is a new breaking point. Thanks Laurenz!